# Using dynamically generated Lambda as input for Linq OrderBy

Tags: c#, linq, sorting, lambda

I want to programatically create Linq OrderBy clauses. So I have tried to dynamically create Lambdas and use them as input for my OrderBy clauses, but it doesn't work. Not sure what the actual input for the OrderBy would be.

What am I missing here?

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        List<Person> people = new List<Person>();
        people.Add(new Person { Age = 10, Name = "D" });
        people.Add(new Person { Age = 20, Name = "C" });
        people.Add(new Person { Age = 30, Name = "B" });
        people.Add(new Person { Age = 40, Name = "A" });

        var paramExpr = Expression.Parameter(typeof(Person), "p");
        var prop = Expression.Property(paramExpr, "Name");

        var lambdaExpr = Expression.Lambda(prop, new List<ParameterExpression>() { paramExpr });
        Console.WriteLine(lambdaExpr); //Outputs p => p.Name


        var sortedPeople = people.OrderBy(lambdaExpr.Compile()); //This doesn't work.
        //var sortedPeople = people.OrderBy(p => p.Name); //This works

        foreach (var person in sortedPeople)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(String.Format("{0} - {1}", person.Name, person.Age));
        }

        Console.ReadKey();
    }
```

Comment: What do you mean by "doesn't work"? Does it not compile? Does it throw an exception at runtime?

Comment: Threw a runtime exception. Have posted answer below, taken from one of the related questions suggested by Stackoverflow.

Answer (score 1):

Just found the answer. The Lambda expression needs to be of type Func

```
var lambdaExpr = Expression.Lambda<Func<Person, object>>(prop, new List<ParameterExpression>() { paramExpr });
```

Then it all works!